# How to use a raw_input value in a line for taking input in python

Tags: python, raw-input

I want to take input as string as raw_input and want to use this value in another line for taking the input in python. My code is below:

```
p1 = raw_input('Enter the name of Player 1 :')
p2 = raw_input('Enter the name of Player 2 :')


p1 = input('Welcome %s > Enter your no:') % p1
```

Here in place of `%s` I want to put the value of `p1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the closing parenthesis to the end of the last line. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @Wooble I disagree. I don't think it should be closed as the user was not 'hey, I am getting this error' but 'how can I do this?' The code he posted was just what he had tried so far, which is a good thing to post.

Comment: @Wooble, thanks for replying to my question, Really this works just moving the parenthesis. Also alex thorton, your code also works by using .format. Which one should I use ?

Comment: @chakladar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do (the vast majority will agree that this is the best way):

```
p1 = input('Welcome {0} > Enter your no:'.format(p1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
input("Welcome " + p1 + "> Enter your no:")
```

It concatenates the value of `p1` to the input string

Also see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
input("Welcome {0}, {1} > Enter your no".format(p1, p2)) #you can have multiple values
```

**EDIT**

Note that using `+` is [discouraged](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: In-place string concatenation with `+` is generally discouraged, see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because Python interprets

```
p1 = input('Welcome %s > Enter your no:') % p1
```

As:

1. Get input, using the prompt `'Welcome %s > Enter your no:'`;
2. Try to insert `p1` into the *text returned by* `input`, which will cause a `TypeError` unless the user's number includes `'%s'`; and
3. Assign the result of that formatting back to `p1`.

The minimal fix here is:

```
p1 = input('Welcome %s > Enter your no:' % p1)
```

which will carry out the `%` formatting *before* using the string as a prompt, but I agree with the other answers that `str.format` is the preferred method for this.